# How to deploy separated backend and frontend on same server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, deployment, frontend, backend

I have developed a project with Vuejs as the front-end and Laravel as the back-end api.In localhost they run in different ports.How should I deploy them in production?

Comment: i understand that you develop the frontend separately using Vue clie?

Comment: You can use subdomain

Comment: You could take your front-end code source and compile it using laravel mix and in this case you could deploy you app in the same address and port

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you build your Vue app for production, all the relevant files are in the `dist` folder. It does not run on any port, but instead the files are served by a webserver (e.g. Apache or Nginx). For a laravel api you normally have the `public` folder in the laravel installation visible, while having the rest of the files not directly accessible from the web.

I am going to assume that you want to deploy the api and the frontend on the same domain. The easiest way of getting this to work is by having a specific prefix for your api. In the case below, I use the prefix `/api` for all api requests, since this is the default for api routes. Anything else is considered a request for the frontend.

You set up your folder structure like the following. The `public_html` folder is what is normally loaded when going to `example.com` and you can test this by adding a `test.txt` file with some content and going to `example.com/test.txt`. The `backend` folder contains your laravel installation. The `frontend` folder contains everything that the `dist` folder contained after running `npm run build`.

```
/var
+-- /www
    +-- /vhosts
        +-- /example.com
            +-- public_html
        +-- /backend
        +-- /frontend
```

To get everything to work, we are going to remove the `public_html` folder and replace it with a symlink to `backend/public`.

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/example.com
rm -r public_html
ln -s ../backend/public public_html
```

When we check `example.com`, we now should see that we can make requests to the api using `example.com/api/someroute`. There are several ways we can make the frontend work with this, but for ease of deployment, lets create a symlink to the dist folder.

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/example.com/public_html
ln -s ../../frontend/dist app
```

If you are using hash mode for your Vue application and don't mind accessing the app through `example.com/app`, I believe this is all you would need to do. Otherwise you would need to modify the `.htaccess` file if you are using Apache, or change the rewrite configuration of whatever other webserver you are using. I imagine the `.htaccess` file would look something like this:

```
# We assume that the FollowSymLinks option is enabled in the main Apache configuration.
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite anything that starts with `api` to the laravel index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Rewrite anything else to the frontend app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /app/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Dear @Sumurai8 thanks for this guide. I've laravel - react application instead of Vue.js. when I run the example.com/app it should show the front end application (index.html) @ front end folder, but the server return a 403 error.

Comment: @Huthaifah Kholi Please ask a new question if you want help with your problem with the button in the top-right. You can link this Q&A in your newly asked question if you think that makes your question clearer. Non of my answer generates a 403 on it's own, so I can't really tell why you would be getting that http status code.